# Linear Algebra - Linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T: \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$ be a linear transformation. Does there exist nonzero vectors $u, v, w$ such that
$$
T(u)+u= T(v)+2v=T(w)+3w=0\ ?
$$

Answer (score 4):

If and only if numbers $-1,-2$ and $-3$  are eigenvalues for your $T$ (for example $T(w)+3w=0 \Leftrightarrow  T(w)=-3w$), but every $T:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ has precisely two eigenvalues, therefore the answer is no.